# How to import Date from .CSV to Teradata tables using Bteq?

Tags: csv, teradata

I am trying to import the data which is exported by using Bteq script but not able to load into another table.

```
.EXPORT report file=E:\t\tgt\report_excel_092702.csv;
.set width 200;
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF;
.SET SEPARATOR ','; 
select  empno,coalesce(ename,'no_name') as ename,coalesce(job,'no_job') as job ,coalesce(hiredate, date) as hiredate,COALESCE(mgr,0) as mgr,COALESCE(sal, 0) as sal,COALESCE(comm, 0) as comm,deptno from emps;
--.EXPORT reset
.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

Database teradata1

report_excel_092702.csv(Exported .csv)

```
 EMPNO  ename       job     hiredate     mgr     sal    comm DEPTNO
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     81/11/17    7839    2850       0    30
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   81/11/17       0    50000      0    10
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    81/09/28    7698    1250    1400    30
```

Bteq script....

```
.import vartext ',' file='E:\t\tgt\report_excel_092702.csv',skip=1;

 DATABASE tetra;
 delete from emp_csv;
.QUIET ON 
.REPEAT * 
 USING 
        empno    (varchar(100))
        ,ename   (varchar(100))
        ,hiredate (varchar(100))

 INSERT INTO emp_csv(empno,ename,hiredate)
        VALUES (
        :empno,
        :ename,
        Cast((:hiredate (Date,Format 'dd.mm.yyyy')) As Date) 
        --cast(hiredate 'yy/mm/dd') as :hiredate
        --CAST( CAST( :hiredate AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')
        );
.QUIT
.LOGOFF
```

Comment: Are you getting a particular error message in your BTEQ log file?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why don't you do just plain CASing since yy/mm/dd casts implicitly to DATE in either BTET or ANSI mode? It works for me with the same dateformat as you have.

.`LOGON dbc, dbc;
.import vartext '|' FILE = /root/ETL/new_revision/report.csv, skip=1;
.REPEAT *
 USING (
     EmpNo VARCHAR(2000)
    ,Name  VARCHAR(2000)
    ,hire_date VARCHAR(2000)
     )
INSERT INTO retail.employee_import
    VALUES (
    :EmpNo,
    :Name,
    CAST(:hire_date AS DATE),
    );
.QUIT
.LOGOFF`